# Different types of caches for Gitlab CI/CD

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a pipeline where I have node_modules for both backend and frontend. I am trying to cache these files throughout the entire pipeline (I have three different stages). What is the difference between doing this:

```
stages:
  - test
  - build
  - deploy

unit:
  stage: test
  image: node:12
  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
    paths:
      - Backend/node_modules
      - Frontend/node_modules
...
```

and

```
stages:
  - test
  - build
  - deploy

cache:
  key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
  paths:
    - Backend/node_modules
    - Frontend/node_modules

unit:
  stage: test
  image: node:12
....
```

Does the second one just provide caching for all stages whereas the first one just provides caching for the test stage?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question

> Does the second one just provide caching for all stages whereas the first one just provides caching for the test stage?

is mostly yes.

Basically, the second one just provide caching for all **jobs** whereas the first one just provides caching for the **`unit` job** (as there could be several other jobs in the same stage, not impacted by this setting then).

See the corresponding documentation (to be bookmarked!):

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#cache

> If `cache` is defined outside the scope of jobs, it means it’s set globally and all jobs will use that definition.

And this semantics is widely applied in the GitLab CI YAML config: for example, if you put an `image:` definition at root level (outside the scope of jobs), it will be also applied globally (but could just as well be redefined (overridden) in a given job anyway).

Comment: why do you need caching for a job? wouldn't the generated files within a job (ex: unit) would be available throughout that entire job?

Comment: It can also be useful for a single job: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/index.html → "caches are used to speed up runs of a given job in subsequent pipelines, by storing downloaded dependencies so that they don’t have to be fetched from the internet again (like npm packages, Go vendor packages, etc.) While the cache could be configured to pass intermediate build results between stages, this should be done with `artifacts` instead […] If defined per job, caches are used: by the same job in a subsequent pipeline; by subsequent jobs in the same pipeline, if they have identical dependencies"

Comment: I see, how do jobs choose which cache to use. Do I need to specify the cache key per job?

Comment: Yes, several configurations are possible: per-job caching (`key: "$CI_JOB_NAME"`), per-branch caching (`key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"`), etc. For details, see the [documentation of `cache:key`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#cachekey) :)

Comment: See also this page for more examples: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/index.html#sharing-caches-across-the-same-branch

Comment: I see, so the only thing I'd have to add to the job would be cache: key: ....?, the paths for the cache would be set at a global scope?

Comment: No, at first sight, the snippets in the doc only mentions `key:` just for readability, but it seems reasonable to put all your `cache` settings in the same place (i.e. below a single `cache:` section gathered in the job(s) you're interested to have cache)